# Приложение останавливается при автостарте

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcast-receiver, android-broadcastreceiver

Когда я запускаю приложение и перезагружаю телефон, ресивер не запускается и выдается уведомление "Приложение MassangerWhite остановлено" 
Может пригодится код ресивера:

```java
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("start");
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),
        "ForegroundStart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
       context.startService(new Intent(context,service.class).putExtra("StartForeground",true));
    }
```

Есть разрешение использования интернета

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Проверте разрешения в манифесте. Ест ли там разрешения на использования интернета...?

   ```
   <manifest xlmns:android...>
   ...
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <application ...
   </manifest>
   ```
2. Попробуйте добавить в манифест ето:

   ```
   <receiver
        android:name=".AutoStart"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >

        <intent-filter android:priority="500" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
   ```
3. Попробуйте следуйщий код:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
    System.out.println("start");
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
    "ForegroundStart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, service.class);
    //myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // можна попробивать ето
    context.startService(myIntent);
    }
   ```

   }
4. Проверте дали ли ви все разрешения приложению на телефоне (в настройках -> приложение MassangerWhite -> разрешения -> ...)
5. **Если ничего не помогло** попробуйте закоментировать часть кода, может пробема не в етом методе

Comment: Есть разрешение использования интернета

Comment: Попробуйте следующие пункти